# Laravel 5.5 minimum requirements

Tags: php, laravel

I am using Ubuntu 17 with php 7.1 and am trying to install Laravel 5.5 but it is telling me to check the minimum requirements.

I can't install the recommended php extensions. I am using sudo add-apt-repository ppa:ondrej/php but it appears the extension are not there and there is a mismatch from the repo

```
Repository 'http://ppa.launchpad.net/ondrej/php/ubuntu artful InRelease' changed its 'Label' value from '***** The main PPA for PHP (5.6, 7.0, 7.1) with many PECL extensions *****' to '***** The main PPA for supported PHP versions with many PECL extensions *****'
```

Comment: What errors does apt throw at you when you try to install them?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your composer should say what extensions you need. 
You also check doc https://laravel.com/docs/master#installation

- PHP >= 7.0.0
- OpenSSL PHP Extension
- PDO PHP Extension
- Mbstring PHP Extension
- Tokenizer PHP Extension
- XML PHP Extension

  sudo apt-get install curl php-curl php-mcrypt php-mbstring php-gettext

Comment: I can't seem to get them from the repo http://ppa.launchpad.net/ondrej/php/ubuntu

Answer (score 0):

**Install PHP 7.1 on Ubuntu**

Use the following set of commands to add PPA for PHP 7 in your Ubuntu system and install it.

```
> sudo apt-get install python-software-properties

> sudo add-apt-repository ppa:ondrej/php

> sudo apt-get update

> sudo apt-get install -y php7.1
```

Now use the following command to check installed php version on your system.

```
> php -v
```

**Install PHP 7 Modules/Extensions**

Find all the available PHP 7 modules using the following command:

```
> sudo apt-cache search php7-*
```

Install required PHP extensions using the following command

```
> sudo apt-get install <extension-name>
```

You can install multiple extensions using the same command. Separate extension names by a space.

For example

```
> sudo apt-get install php7.1-xml php7.1-xmlrpc php7.1-zip
```

**Laravel 5.5 System Requirements Checker**

To verify system requirements for Laravel 5.5 you can then use the following simple app.
https://github.com/mitesh1409/laravel-system-requirements-checker

Do git clone of this repo inside your server's root directory and then execute it.

For example using Apache server on Ubuntu 16.04, do git clone of this repo inside "var/www/html". It will create an app folder named "laravel-system-requirements-checker". Now you can run this using the url "http://localhost/laravel-system-requirements-checker/".

I hope this will help everyone starting development on Laravel 5.5.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Laravel-Requirement-Checker from browser

https://github.com/hosamalzagh/Laravel-Requirement-Checker