# Loading composer repositories with package information Updating dependencies (including require-dev)

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, message

Loading composer repositories with package information
Updating dependencies (including require-dev)

My computer shows that: what does it mean??

And also :

```
Problem 1
  - This package requires php ^7.1.3 but your PHP version (5.6.30) does not satisfy that requirement.
Problem 2
  - laravel/framework v5.6.9 requires php ^7.1.3 -> your PHP version (5.6.30) does not satisfy that requirement.
  - laravel/framework v5.6.8 requires php ^7.1.3 -> your PHP version (5.6.30) does not satisfy that requirement.
  - laravel/framework v5.6.7 requires php ^7.1.3 -> your PHP version (5.6.30) does not satisfy that requirement.
  - laravel/framework v5.6.6 requires php ^7.1.3 -> your PHP version (5.6.30) does not satisfy that requirement.
  - laravel/framework v5.6.5 requires php ^7.1.3 -> your PHP version (5.6.30) does not satisfy that requirement.
  - laravel/framework v5.6.4 requires php ^7.1.3 -> your PHP version (5.6.30) does not satisfy that requirement.
  - laravel/framework v5.6.3 requires php ^7.1.3 -> your PHP version (5.6.30) does not satisfy that requirement.
  - laravel/framework v5.6.27 requires php ^7.1.3 -> your PHP version (5.6.30) does not satisfy that requirement.
  - laravel/framework v5.6.26 requires php ^7.1.3 -> your PHP version (5.6.30) does not satisfy that requirement.
  - laravel/framework v5.6.25 requires php ^7.1.3 -> your PHP version (5.6.30) does not satisfy that requirement.
  - laravel/framework v5.6.24 requires php ^7.1.3 -> your PHP version (5.6.30) does not satisfy that requirement.
  - laravel/framework v5.6.23 requires php ^7.1.3 -> your PHP version (5.6.30) does not satisfy that requirement.
  - laravel/framework v5.6.22 requires php ^7.1.3 -> your PHP version (5.6.30) does not satisfy that requirement.
  - laravel/framework v5.6.21 requires php ^7.1.3 -> your PHP version (5.6.30) does not satisfy that requirement.
  - laravel/framework v5.6.20 requires php ^7.1.3 -> your PHP version (5.6.30) does not satisfy that requirement.
  - laravel/framework v5.6.2 requires php ^7.1.3 -> your PHP version (5.6.30) does not satisfy that requirement.
  - laravel/framework v5.6.19 requires php ^7.1.3 -> your PHP version (5.6.30) does not satisfy that requirement.
  - laravel/framework v5.6.18 requires php ^7.1.3 -> your PHP version (5.6.30) does not satisfy that requirement.
  - laravel/framework v5.6.17 requires php ^7.1.3 -> your PHP version (5.6.30) does not satisfy that requirement.
  - laravel/framework v5.6.16 requires php ^7.1.3 -> your PHP version (5.6.30) does not satisfy that requirement.
  - laravel/framework v5.6.15 requires php ^7.1.3 -> your PHP version (5.6.30) does not satisfy that requirement.
  - laravel/framework v5.6.14 requires php ^7.1.3 -> your PHP version (5.6.30) does not satisfy that requirement.
  - laravel/framework v5.6.13 requires php ^7.1.3 -> your PHP version (5.6.30) does not satisfy that requirement.
  - laravel/framework v5.6.12 requires php ^7.1.3 -> your PHP version (5.6.30) does not satisfy that requirement.
  - laravel/framework v5.6.11 requires php ^7.1.3 -> your PHP version (5.6.30) does not satisfy that requirement.
  - laravel/framework v5.6.10 requires php ^7.1.3 -> your PHP version (5.6.30) does not satisfy that requirement.
  - laravel/framework v5.6.1 requires php ^7.1.3 -> your PHP version (5.6.30) does not satisfy that requirement.
  - laravel/framework v5.6.0 requires php ^7.1.3 -> your PHP version (5.6.30) does not satisfy that requirement.
  - laravel/framework 5.6.x-dev requires php ^7.1.3 -> your PHP version (5.6.30) does not satisfy that requirement.
  - Installation request for laravel/framework 5.6.* -> satisfiable by laravel/framework[5.6.x-dev, v5.6.0, v5.6.1, v5.6.10, v5.6.11, v5.6.12, v5.6.13, v5.6.14, v5.6.15, v5.6.16, v5.6.17, v5.6.18, v5.6.19, v5.6.2, v5.6.20, v5.6.21, v5.6.22, v5.6.23, v5.6.24, v5.6.25, v5.6.26, v5.6.27, v5.6.3, v5.6.4, v5.6.5, v5.6.6, v5.6.7, v5.6.8, v5.6.9].
```

Comment: I would venture that `^7.1.3` is not trivial to understand.

Comment: Install PHP7 lol

Answer (score 2):

Whole Composer supports the simple and familiar >= and similar signs they have abbreviations which are completely obscure.

In this case, you have a [caret version range](https://getcomposer.org/doc/articles/versions.md#caret-version-range-)

> For example ^1.2.3 is equivalent to >=1.2.3 <2.0.0

It seems you asked for some minor version of Laravel 5.6 which wants a PHP 7 version, at least 7.1.3. You are running PHP 5.6.30. Looking at https://stackoverflow.com/a/47737108/308851 tells me not even the Laravel LTS version, 5.5 would help you out -- that requires 7.0.0 at least.

Comment: Awesome, it fixed